# Use Methods from Dropped Object in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-droppable

I would like to use a method of an dragged and dropped Object.

```
function Controller(){
        $( "#container" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var draggable = ui.draggable;
            alert( "Dropped:" + draggable.attr('id'));
            draggable.myMethod();

        }

});
```

Could you explain why this doesnt work?
The alert shows that the right Object ist dropped,
but i cant use the method.

The Object looks like this:

```
function Icon(name) {
var name = name;
this.myMethod = function() {
    alert("test")};
    this.getInfo = function() {  
    var dataname = this.getName();

    //BErtram
    $("#" + dataname).draggable({ revert: "valid" });
    //Bertram Ende


}
}
```

**Edit:**

If I invoke the Method this way:

```
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var draggable = ui.draggable;
            alert(...);
            var ic = new Icon("asdsa");
            ic.myMethod();
        },
```

it works, but I want to use the Method on the dragged Object, do I have to do some sort of typecasting?

**Edit: Workaround**
Finally i used a workaround, using a bool to check if there was a succesfull drop and invoking the method in draggable.stop if the boolean ist true. The state of the boolean is set to true in the droppable on a succesfull drop and set to false in draggable.start.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you clarify what "doesn't work" means? Do you get any output in your browsers debugger or any information that might help someone out with your problem?

Comment: Ty, i use Mozilla, it says "myMethod is not a function"

Comment: The Browser simple stops. I tried several things, but I just cant invoke that method in the Controller class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `myMethod` is a function on the `Icon` object you create, however the `ui.draggable` is not an instance of `Icon` - so it has no `myMethod` method.

Comment: Can i do some sort of typecasting to fix this Problem?

Comment: The `ui.draggable` isn't giving you back the object you think you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

The `ui.draggable` value is a DOM element contained inside a jQuery object.  You need a mechanism to map from the element back to the `Icon` that's responsible for it.

The simplest method is to use `.data()`:

```
function Icon(name) {
    $('#' + name).data('self', this);
    ...
}
```

and then retrieve that object in the event handler:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
    var icon = draggable.data('self');
    icon.myMethod();
}
```

Comment: Ty for this idea, it looks good. I think thats what Iam looking for. I still get an error saying: "cannot call Mehod "myMethod" on undefined. I guess my mapping still doesnt throw back the right Object. Working on this.

Comment: Is it possible to get a direct reference to the Object without going the way over 'ID'? Here it works sometimes, but some ID'S are the same so I dont get the right results.

Comment: @user2148566  you can't use duplicate IDs in HTML.